# How to write a Matlab-struct to an Excel file?

Tags: matlab

I know about xlswrite which convert workspace variable into excel but it is restricted to numerical, cell and logical array but I have got struct type data. I have also tried to save the workspace variable it does not work out and I am not so expert that's why I did not try to mess with the library either.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

[image: workspace variable]

[image: output command window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go via a table and `writetable`

```
writetable( struct2table( stats ), 'myFile.xlsx' );
```

The function [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) is quite flexible about data types *within a table*, but requires a table input. In the case of your scalar struct, this will give a nice table with column headings corresponding to your struct fields.

If you want something more bespoke you will have to build the table manually rather than using `struct2table`. For instance you might want to do:

```
FieldName = fieldnames( stats );
Value = cellfun( @(f) stats.(f), FieldName );

T = table( FieldName, Value );
writetable( T, 'myFile.xslx' );
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked, though I had to remove the number of parameter

Answer (score 1):

can you create a `table()` from your data (try `struct2table()` but in future, format it directly as a table)? This is the most similar object as an excel file so writing to it is easy: [`writetable()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Xlswrite(filename,A) : A is a matrix. Convert A as in your case to the cell and then to matrix. the command will be as:
xlswrite(filename,cell2mat(struct2cell(A));